# Unable To Resolve Exception Class: ZXing

Tags: java, android, zxing

I have a project that runs perfectly fine on newer devices and API levels, however, I'm getting some issues on emulators. When I load up the application on an emulator, I get this issue:

```
02-22 18:36:11.584: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 872 (Lcom/google/zxing/WriterException;)
02-22 18:36:11.584: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x7da
02-22 18:36:11.584: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/myapp/Card;.getFrontView (Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;
02-22 18:36:11.584: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x07da
02-22 18:36:11.584: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/myapp/Card;.getFrontView (Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;
02-22 18:36:11.584: W/dalvikvm(652): Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/myapp/Card;
```

Which then leads to an evident `java.lang.VerifyError` for the `Card` class.

The problem is coming up with the `WriterException` class, but that class is just:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2008 ZXing authors
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.google.zxing;

/**
 * A base class which covers the range of exceptions which may occur when encoding a barcode using
 * the Writer framework.
 *
 * @author dswitkin@google.com (Daniel Switkin)
 */
public final class WriterException extends Exception {

  public WriterException() {
  }

  public WriterException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }

  public WriterException(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
  }

}
```

Maybe I'm missing something as to why this is causing an issue on older API levels, but that's the reason why I'm asking this here! I appreciate the collective and mass knowledge at SO.

EDIT:

I tried removing the thrown WriterException by handling it inside a deeper in class. That prevented that issue I was getting as listed above (still not sure why). However, a new issue has arisen!

I think this may have to do with my library not being read properly. I have a User Library with the ZXing `core.jar` inside of it. The .jar lists every class and will open it all, but I'm getting:

```
02-22 18:56:49.564: W/dalvikvm(688): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat;)
02-22 18:56:49.604: E/dalvikvm(688): Could not find class 'com.google.zxing.EncodeHintType', referenced from method Barcode.BarcodeGenerator.encodeAsBitmap
02-22 18:56:49.604: W/dalvikvm(688): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 869 (Lcom/google/zxing/EncodeHintType;) in LBarcode/BarcodeGenerator;
02-22 18:56:49.604: D/dalvikvm(688): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0011
02-22 18:56:49.604: E/dalvikvm(688): Could not find class 'com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter', referenced from method Barcode.BarcodeGenerator.encodeAsBitmap
02-22 18:56:49.604: W/dalvikvm(688): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 870 (Lcom/google/zxing/MultiFormatWriter;) in LBarcode/BarcodeGenerator;
```

in my warnings now. I'm really stumped with all of this..

[Here is a screenshot of the User Library, called ZXing, that I have added to my project's Java Build Path > Libraries.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXRea.png)

Comment: @DigCamara I'm declaring: android:minSdkVersion="8" and android:targetSdkVersion="17"

Comment: @RileyE where did you put your external jar libraries?

Comment: The SDK level would have nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing to do with `WriterException` and you should not have to modify the code. The library itself is fine. You can see that actually many classes are missing, probably all of them. You have not actually included the library. Since you say you repackaged it, the problem is there. The classes aren't in the `.jar` correctly, or maybe you included it as a `.jar` in a `.jar`.

Comment: You probably know best (having created the library) but could the problem stem from his use of the library in an emulator? My guess would be that, since he's using it in an emulator, it doesn't find the hardware devices and/or software that it's seeking.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, however I missed your response. I've included the library as a user library and the files are all listed in my ADT / Eclipse menu. I've included a screenshot in my original post of my User Library containing the ZXing core.jar and its contents. Maybe it can't be a user library? I don't know why its acting as it is.

Comment: Wow. I just realized you're the primary author of ZXing. So, what I've done is build the core project into a core.jar and then added that to a clean User Library. As you can see, I have all of the files listed under the library inside ADT / Eclipse, so I would figure that they're all there and should work. The problem initially started when I moved the library core.jar path from a local directory to a dropbox directory. The library path is correct and everything seems to be in order. That is why I'm so confused.

Comment: I don't know if that's enough or not, I don't use Eclipse. The message is saying that your projects does not bundle this library. Normally put it in `libs/` is all that's necessary and all I do. The CL tools build it in correctly then. Look at the `android/` code.

Comment: @SeanOwen Weird. I'm not getting notifications for any of your posts. As for what you said, my application used to run 100% fine until I moved everything to dropbox. That is when the issues started occurring and now I can't get them to stop, even with rebuilding the core.jar and whatnot. I have also worked with putting the libraries into `/libs`, but I'm still getting the same error. Its really frustrating because I can clearly see the library in the build path and the classes that it "can't find" inside the core.jar.