# Issues With emulator in Eclipse/ADT

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm having some inconsistent errors when testing my code. I have a number of external libraries installed and even some issues with code I wrote.

I will run a project on an emulated device and then the exact same project on the actual device (Same make and API level) and I frequently get issues/crashes for rejected classes and missing files on the emulator, but not on the actual device (Where everything runs just fine). Is this something that just happens?

If this is just something that happens, how can I go about testing on a number of different devices? I don't mind buying them, however I don't know which ones to get, or where to get them from. I guess I just need to know how I should go about developing for Android, given my issues.

Comment: You need to post your logcat to see what kind of errors you're getting. It's quite likely you didn't load the correct libraries, though.

Comment: @DigCamara I was mentioning this in a general sense as I've had a number of questions with inconsistencies between device and simulator. If you're looking for a specific issue, please look at my other question that you commented on.

Comment: @DigCamara http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035235/unable-to-resolve-exception-class-zxing#comment21131052_15035235

Comment: Well, given that you're using ZXing which (correct me if I'm wrong) is actually an external library, you might have to verify the compatibility issues for that particular library.

Comment: @DigCamara Its giving the same error on API level 17 emulators.

Comment: Can you post the actual stack trace of your logcat? so that people here can assess what really the problem is.

Comment: @hardcoded I'm not sure what you mean. The stack traces, in my specific questions that aren't this one, have been posted on their respective questions. The one listed above is an example.

Comment: @RileyE you said there are inconsistent errors crashes. All errors and exceptions are logged in your logcat and those logs are your stack trace.

Comment: @hardcoded And I've posted those in their questions. You can see one of them here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035235/unable-to-resolve-exception-class-zxing#comment21131052_15035235